# Highcharts - add a second needle to a VU Meter with a different colour

Tags: highcharts, gauge

Is there a way to add a second needle of a different colour to a VU Meter ('gauge') style chart in Highcharts?  I know that you can change the colour of the needle per chart using plotOptions:gauge:dial e.g.

```
plotOptions: {
        gauge: {
            dial: {
                radius: '100%',
                backgroundColor : 'grey'
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have tried to overlay a second pane and specify individual plotOptions (as per this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jdalton/xfV5k/8/) but without any success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same options as in plotOptions directly in series:

```
 series: [{
        data: [{y:-6, color: 'red'}],
        yAxis: 0,
        dial: {
            backgroundColor : 'red'
        }
 }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xfV5k/11/

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was looking for.  Just couldn't get the right syntax.